# Как заверстать QWidget в QML

Tags: qt, qt5

как вставить QWidget в QML и вывести QML, в котором будет весь виджет QWidget.

Для чего нужно?
Чтобы все окно (кнопки, bg, label на QWidget) подтачивалось под размер экрана на андроид через QML

Имеется ли у кого-то такой код? А то я вообще найти такого не могу

Comment: в общем говоря QWidget и QML это разные API на одной как-бы не очень высокой базе, благодарить за этот бардак следует Нокию, которая на этом обанкротилась. Смешать можно, но лучше не надо, первое с чем столкнётесь, это модальные состояния у каждого свои

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, Кхм...А как на QWidget сделать автоматическую подборку разрешений?

Comment: какую автоматическую подборку?

Comment: @ Pavel Gridin, я имею ввиду, чтобы приложение при запуске подбирало ширину и высоту экрана андроид и выставляло его QWidget со смещением координат объектов

Comment: setlayout на окно и оно растянется